# Inconsistent behaviour of @link in createSchemaCustomization when using JSON imported data

Tags: graphql, gatsby

On my Gatsby site I have a series of JSON files that are being parsed by [gatsby-transformer-json](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-transformer-json/) and [gatsby-source-filesystem](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-source-filesystem/) so I can query them with GraphQL.

I have structured the data so I can use `@link` to create foreign keys between the files.  When running locally, this was only working and linking the data on a few rows, but not all of them - despite the correct keys.

I re-ordered the JSON file and suddenly all rows were appearing correctly with the linked data - despite no data changes.  However, when I deploy my site to Netlify the issue comes back, but on different rows of the data.

This is an example of JSON files:

```
// src/data/work.json

[{
  "title": "This is my project title",
  "category: "website",
  "tags": ["html", "css", "javascript"]
}, {
  "title": "This is another project",
  "category: "app",
  "tags": ["php", "mysql"]
}]
```

```
// src/data/categories.json

[{
  "id": "website",
  "title": "A Website"
}, {
  "id": "app",
  "title": "A Web-App"
}]
```

```
// src/data/tags.json

[{
  "id": "html",
  "title": "HTML Markup"
}, {
  "id": "css",
  "title": "CSS styling"
},
{
  // etc
}]
```

My `gatsby-config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    'gatsby-transformer-json',
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
      options: {
        path: './src/data',
        name: 'data',
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

And my `gatsby-node.js` file:

```
exports.createSchemaCustomization = ({ actions }) => {
  const { createTypes } = actions;

  const typeDefs = `
    type WorkJson implements Node {
      category: CategoriesJson @link
      tags: [TagsJson] @link
    }
  `;

  createTypes(typeDefs);
};
```

I have been following the [documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/schema-customization/#foreign-key-fields) regarding this, but I can't understand the inconsistent behaviour, what may be causing it, or how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have resolved this.  It's a niche situation, but the answer may help someone in the future.

In short, the issue is naming the field `"id"` in my .json files - as Gatsby is trying to automatically set this value itself, and I can only assume this is occasionally causing issues.

By changing my JSON files to use a different field name for the "ID", e.g.:

```
// src/data/categories.json

[{
  "key": "website",
  "title": "A Website"
}, {
  "key": "app",
  "title": "A Web-App"
}]
```

And then updating my `gatsby-node.js` to **@link** based on the new field name:

```
exports.createSchemaCustomization = ({ actions }) => {
  const { createTypes } = actions;

  const typeDefs = `
    type WorkJson implements Node {
      category: CategoriesJson @link(by: "key")
      tags: [TagsJson] @link(by: "key")
    }
  `;

  createTypes(typeDefs);
};
```

Everything then started to behave as expected.